# Access a Self signed HTTPS C# service from other C# service in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ssl, https, .net-core, libcurl

I run a Self-signed (HTTPS) C# web server for my local testing.I can't access this C# application-1 from other c# applications that running in the same PC. Other Applications show error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
```

```
System.Net.Http.CurlException: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

My certificate is not signed by CA. But I run my application only in my system. Also I added my certificate to  trusted CA root store using the following command

> certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n "localhost" -i localhost.crt

But still got the same error from the second c# application.My system OS is ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpHandler has a ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback, which you can override to perform custom certificate validation.

```
private HttpClient CustomHttpClient()
{
    return new HttpClient(
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = cert_validation,
        }); 
}

private bool cert_validation(HttpRequestMessage reqMsg, X509Certificate2 cert, X509Chain certChain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    //custom validation
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 cert/private_key
1_root
2_intermediate
3_application

The 3_application to your APP ( don't forget to generate with correct cname/alias for host and IP)

And the public part of root and intermediate(CA) add/installed on the system that run the second APP

This script should help
https://github.com/nicholasjackson/mtls-go-example/blob/master/generate.sh

Comment: could you please elaborate on the answer. something I got much error while running script.

Comment: https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

Comment: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/ssl-certificates-explained/